# How to add each element in of two list using stream api in java

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

```
partnersName =["partner1","partner2"];

totalDates = ["2022-05-18","2022-05-19"];
```

both the lists store string only

here is the following code which gives output that I want

```
 for (int i = 0; i < partnersName.size(); i++) {
        if (totalDates.isEmpty()) {
            totalDates.add(partnersName.get(i));
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalDates.size(); j++) {
                totalDates.set(j, partnersName.get(i) +"/" +totalDates.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

> output
> =["partner1/2022-05-18","partner2/2022-05-18","partner1/2022-05-19","partner2/2022-05-19"];

but I want to reduce the line of code using stream. Anyone could help to get stream API code

Comment: What have you trie so far?

Comment: i am complete new to java could you pls help me

Comment: I wonder what the real intention of doing so is?

Comment: to reduce lines of code

Comment: Your output isn't what your code is producing. Your code yields `[partner2/partner1/2022-05-18, partner2/partner1/2022-05-19]`

Comment: then just remove all new-line and you will have just one line, can't reduce more, but it will be hard to read and maintain - in other words, very bad goal... better aim for easier to understand/read/maintain code (even if more lines of code needed - like it is also better to have descriptive variable names instead of single-letter ones) BTW using streams will not necessarily be faster or use less memory

Comment: atleast can i get the stream api code, that will be helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
List<String> partnerName = List.of("partner1","partner2");
List<String> totalDates = List.of("2022-05-18","2022-05-19");

List<String> result = partnerName.stream()
        .flatMap(name -> totalDates.stream()
                .map(date->String.join("/", name, date)))
        .toList();
    
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
[partner1/2022-05-18, partner1/2022-05-19, partner2/2022-05-18, partner2/2022-05
-19]
```

- The above uses nested streams to process each List.
- `String.join` - takes a delimiter and a variable number of arguments and concatenates them, separated by the delimiter.
- `flatMap` flattens the nested streams into one for conversion to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the result `[partner1/2022-05-18, partner1/2022-05-19, partner2/2022-05-18, partner2/2022-05-19]` is what you want:

```
List<String> result = partnersName.stream().<String>mapMulti((s, stringConsumer) -> totalDates.forEach(d -> stringConsumer.accept(s + "/" + d))).toList();
```

Comment: alternative: `partnersName.stream().map("/"::concat).flatMap(p -> totalDates.stream().map(p::concat)).toList();` - but not sure if really "*that will be helpful*" as requested in comment :-/

Comment: @user16320675 I'd assume `.map(s -> s.concat("/"))` right? Else we'd have `/partner12022-05-18` etc :)

Comment: You might want to explain the required `type witness` on `mapMulti`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be

```java
List<String> result = partnersName.stream()
                        .flatMap(x -> totalDates.stream().map(y -> x.concat("/"+y)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

//output: [partner1/2022-05-18, partner1/2022-05-19, partner2/2022-05-18, partner2/2022-05-19]
```